# Compare new values to previous values and flag if not the same within Excel (Using Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, within Excel that contains values that I wish to compare to previous values.  If the current value does not compare to the previous value, I wish to highlight the cell within excel.

This is my data:

```
COL1  match
9     1  False
8     3  False
2     2  True
3     1  False
4     2  False
5     2  False
```

Desired Outcome:

```
df['match'] = df.COL1.eq(df.COL1.shift())
print (df)


COL1  match
9     1  False
8     3  False
2     2  True
3     1  False
4     2  False
5     2  False
```

And highlight the 'False' values within Excel

This is what I am doing:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('c:\\temp\\df.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

def highlight_cells():
return ['background-color: yellow']
df.style.apply(highlight_cells)     

df['match'] = df.COL1.eq(df.COL1.shift())
```

I am unsure of how to put this all together, ultimately highlighting any cells within Excel that do not match previous values. I am currently researching.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

***Updated***

This is what I did:

```
 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Book1.xlsx')
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()



 cell_format = workbook.add_format()


 cell_format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
 cell_format.set_bg_color('green')

 for index, row in df.iterrows():
      if row.Row1 == row.Row2:
           worksheet.write("B"+str(index+1), 'Ray', cell_format)  
    
    
    
    
 df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by applying an Excel conditional format to the cells like this:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   'Data2': [11, 20, 30, 21, 15, 31, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add a format. Green fill with dark green text.
green_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                                    'font_color': '#006100'})

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format(1, 2, 7, 2, {'type':     'cell',
                                          'criteria': 'equal to',
                                          'value':    '=$B2',
                                          'format':   green_format})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This works, but how would I highlight the cells that are not matching? Would I just put ‘criteria : not equal to?

Comment: Correct. See the XlsxWriter docs on Working with Conditional Formatting: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html You can also overlap conditional formats if you want to highlight both matching and non-matching.

Comment: Can this  'value':    '=$B2',   be a range?   (I am wanting to apply this to rows)

Row1     1  2  3  4  5 
Row2     1  2  3  4  6

I am trying to compare these two rows (horizontally) and flag/highlight the one cells that do not match. How would I 'fix' this? $B2 wouldn't work I do not think, so can I apply a range?

Comment: It is hard to say without a more detailed example. The best thing to do is to figure out the conditional format in Excel and apply it to the Python code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to set background to a cell

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()

cell_format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
cell_format.set_bg_color('green')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.COL1 == row.match:
       worksheet.write("B"+str(index+1), 'Ray', cell_format)    #there you need to put the required cell like A1 or B2 or similar
```

Docs: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_bg_color

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I am trying this now

Comment: plz improve the answer after you have written your complete code.

Comment: Hi @Vishesh I have updated my post with what I did. I do not see that the cells have highlighted. Did I do this correctly?